# Recovery from CAN Bus-off State

Tags: embedded, can-bus

In CAN network. if a node goes to Bus-off it has to wait for 128 occurrences of 11 consecutive recessive bits. So my question is why only 11 recessive bits, is there any specific reason to follow that standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Frame**:

11 bits = 1 bit ACK Delimiter + 7 End-Of-Frame + 3 IFS

**Error Frame:**

11 bits  = 8 Error Delimiter + 3 IFS

so it means you need to wait for:

- 128 occurrences of successful Data Frames or Error Frames.
- Or simply 128 occurrences of 11 consecutive recessive bits.

to recover from Bus-Off.

The best case is in idle state (when bus state is recessive), suppose the baud rate is 1Mb/s(so 1 bit time is 1us), you need to wait totally 128*11*1us = 1408us.

Comment: Thank You. And i've one more doubt, CAN node should receive 128 times above mentioned frames successfully to recover from Bus-Off. my question is, **is there any specific reason to keep 128 times?** @Nik

Comment: @Arun it's the experience practice and they found 128 times is good enough. Practically, people don't use this rule to recover from bus-off, most of the Can Controller allow use to implement your own rule (like wait for 40ms to recover).

Comment: Thank You @Nik. What they will do in mean time, they will just wait or any recovery mechanism they will follow ? If they just wait it means again the same problem gets repeat, so what is the necessity of waiting instead of stopping the transmission of other messages for recovery time.

Comment: @Arun they will just wait and after that amount of time, they try to get back to the bus. If the error keeps happening, they will need a mechanism to report the error, ex: in Autosar, they try to do the fast recovery and slow recovery, if after all, still bus-off, they report it to Error Management module. 
Refer this in 7.7 
https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/3-0/AUTOSAR_SWS_CAN_StateManager.pdf

Answer (score 0):

when REC value  reaches 256  enter in to BUS OFF state so to recover from that 128 times 11 recessive bit needs to send for to recover,  128 is half of 256 where it will enter active fault state.